# Rails 3.2 DoubleRenderError in controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a custom controller action as listed below.  I have a form with checkboxes that allow me to print the selected items by writing them to a pdf file using Prawn. Any Ideas?

I'm getting the following error.

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple
times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and
at most once per action.
```

Here is the relevant part of the controller

```
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :client, :name, :full => true
  autocomplete :product, :product_name, :full => true, :extra_data => [:product_code, :miller_product_code]

  respond_to :js, :html
def index
  if params[:status]
    @openshipments = Shipment.where(:status => params[:status]).search(params[:search1]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).page(params[:page])
  else
    @shipments = Shipment.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).page(params[:page])
  end
end
def create
  ...
end
def edit
  ... 
end
def update
  ... 
end
def destroy
  ...
end

def print_open
  @printshipments = Shipment.find(params[:open_shipment_ids])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      @printshipments.each do |shipment|
        pdf = Prawn::Document.new
        pdf.text "bill_of_lading_#{shipment.bill_of_lading}"
       #removed send_data pdf.render, filename: "bill_of_lading_#{shipment.bill_of_lading}"
        File.open("public/bill_of_ladings/bill_of_lading_#{shipment.bill_of_lading}.pdf", "wb") { |f| f << pdf.render }
        shipment.update_attribute(:status, "PRINTED")

      end
    end
  end
  redirect_to shipments_path
end
```

EDIT:
I can get rid of the error by removing the send_data line, however I can't get the form to redirect to the page I want.  It only wants to render the javacript in the directory, possibly because this is a remote form.  I am calling the print_open through a form_tag that uses the following route.

```
  get '/shipments/status/:status' => 'shipments#index'
```

When I use the redirect_to shipments_path at the end of my print_open method,  It renders the view, but the url in the browser still reads as:

```
http://localhost:3000/shipments/status/open
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:3000/shipments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looping over an array and calling `send_data` on each element, it's possible you're calling `send_data` more than once. That would give you the exception that you're receiving.

Comment: So how do I get the desired output?  Do I need send_data?

Comment: What is your desired output? A PDF with a list of items on it?

Comment: My desired output is to write the pdf's to the "public/bill_of_ladings" directory and then refresh the view.  So far it will write the first pdf in the loop.

Comment: So remove the `send_data` line. After the loop, output whatever it is you want to output.

Comment: I edited the question above to update the issue I'm having with redirecting.  You've been very helpful so far.  I just need to tie up this loose ends.

Comment: Ah, it's a remote form? You'll need to redirect on the Javascript side using `window.location = ...` when the AJAX request comes back.